# Script taking around 6 times more time in php then perl

Tags: php, perl

My PHP script is taking almost 6 times more time than PERL script, my script is to write xml file for sitemap, in this process i am fetching 20k data from DB in one go and writing xml for that after writing that XML file again fetching data for another 20k and again writing another xml file, this way i am creating around 650 xml files, each contains 20k sitemap records. Means We are fetching data from DB around 650 times.

Please help in reducing this time or suggest any alternative solution.

```
public function SitemapGenerate($dbh='')
    {
        global $sthsplit;
        $total_count=0;
        $sql= 'select count(1) COUNT from some_table';
        $sth = oci_parse($dbh,$sql);
        oci_execute($sth);
        oci_fetch_all($sth, $res);
        oci_close($dbh);
        $total_count = $res['COUNT'][0];
        $start=1; $end =20000;
        $succesMsg = $this->fetch_data($start,$end,$total_count,$dbh);
//         oci_close($dbh);
        sleep(1);
    }
    public function fetch_data($start,$end,$total_count)
    {
            $sqlsplit = '';
            $dbh = $this->connect('abc','abc','db');
            $sqlsplit = "select * from some_table where rn between $start and $end";
            $sthsplit = oci_parse($dbh,$sqlsplit);
            oci_execute($sthsplit);
            oci_close($dbh);
            $this->splitquery($sthsplit,$total_count,$dbh);
    }

    public function removeControllCharfunction($str)
    {
            $str = preg_replace( "/&lt;/", '<', $str );
            $str = preg_replace( "/&gt;/", '>', $str );
            $str = preg_replace( "/(<\s*a\b.*?\/\s*a\s*>)|(<\s*\/?\s*a\b.*?\s*>)/", ' ', $str );
            $str = preg_replace( "/(<\s*img\b.*?\s*>)/", ' ', $str );
            $str = preg_replace( "/(http\:\/\/|www\.)(.*?)[^\s\<]*/", ' ', $str );
            $str = preg_replace( "/\b([\w\-\_\.]*?)(\@[\w\-\_\.]*?)(\s+?|$)/", ' ', $str );
            $str = preg_replace("/\&/","&amp;",$str);
            return ($str);
    }

    public function splitquery($sthsplit,$total_count,$dbh)
    {
            global $filePath,$no_of_files,$file_num,$start_time,$global_record,$no_of_files_mb;
            $counter = $ID = $NAME = $records = $cron_time = $time_end = 0;
            $xml = $file_name = $imagePath = $largeimagePath = $fullpath = $final_xml = $title = $fullpath_mb = $xml_mb = $final_xml_mb = $file_name_mb = $final_xml_mb1 = $final_xml1 = '';
            $ha = array();

            while($ha = oci_fetch_array($sthsplit,OCI_ASSOC))
            {
                    $counter++; $valid=0;$records++;$global_record++;
                    $ID   = $ha['ID'];
                    $NAME = $ha['TITLE'];
                    $NAME = strtolower($NAME);
                    $NAME = preg_replace("/^\s+|\s+$/","",$NAME);
                    $NAME = preg_replace("/[ \'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:\"\<\>,\.\?\\\]+/","-",$NAME);
                    $NAME = preg_replace("/^-|-$/","",$NAME);
                    $title   = $ha['TITLE'];
                    $title   = $this->removeControllCharfunction($title);

                    //Mobile Sitemap Code Start here//
                    $fullpath_mb = "https://somepath?i=$ID";
                    $xml_mb="<url><loc>$fullpath_mb</loc><mobile:mobile/></url>\n";
                    $final_xml_mb .= $xml_mb;
                    //Mobile Sitemap code ends here//
                    $fullpath=<<<EOT
https://www.somepath/$NAME-$ID.html
EOT;
                    $xml     =<<<EOT
<url><loc>$fullpath</loc>
EOT;
                    $imagePath      = (isset($ha['PHOTO']) && $ha['PHOTO'] != '') ? $ha['PHOTO'] : '';
                    $largeimagePath = (isset($ha['LARGE_PHOTO']) && $ha['LARGE_PHOTO'] != '') ? $ha['LARGE_PHOTO'] : '';
                    $imagePath      = $this->changeImghostDomain($imagePath);
                    $largeimagePath = $this->changeImghostDomain($largeimagePath);
                    $imagePath      = preg_replace("/\&/","%26",$imagePath);
                    $largeimagePath = preg_replace("/\&/","%26",$largeimagePath);
                    $largeimagePath = preg_replace("/http:/","https:",$largeimagePath);

                    if((isset($largeimagePath)) && (!(preg_match("/add-image.gif$/i", $largeimagePath) > 0)) && ($largeimagePath != '') && (!(preg_match("/coming-soon.gif$/i", $largeimagePath) > 0)) && (!(preg_match("/ts\/t_product_sample/i", $largeimagePath) > 0)) && (preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG)$/i", $largeimagePath) > 0) && (preg_match("/imimg\.com/i", $largeimagePath) > 0))
                    {
                            $xml .=<<<EOT
<image:image><image:loc>$largeimagePath</image:loc><image:title>$title</image:title></image:image>
EOT;
                            $valid=1;
                    }
                    else if((isset($imagePath)) && (!(preg_match("/imimg\.com/i", $imagePath) > 0)) && ($imagePath != '') && (!(preg_match("/coming-soon.gif$/i", $imagePath) > 0)) && (!(preg_match("/ts\/t_product_sample/i", $imagePath) > 0)) && (preg_match("/(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|JPG|JPEG|GIF|PNG)$/i", $imagePath) > 0) && (preg_match("/imimg\.com/i", $largeimagePath) > 0))
                    {
                            $xml .=<<<EOT
<image:image><image:loc>$imagePath</image:loc><image:title>$title</image:title></image:image>
EOT;
                            $valid=1;
                    }
                    $xml .=<<<EOT
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://somepath?i={$ha['ID']}" /></url>\n
EOT;
                    $final_xml .= $xml;
                    if($counter==20000)
                    {
//                     echo "not real: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024)." MiB\n";
                            $file_num++;
                            $counter=0;
                            $final_xml1 =<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">\n$final_xml</urlset>
EOT;
                            $file_name ="$filePath/$file_num.xml";
                            $no_of_files .=<<<EOT
https://www.somepath$file_num.xml (Have Complete 20000 Url's)\n
EOT;

                            $myfile = fopen($file_name, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$file_name \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
                            fwrite($myfile,$final_xml1);
                            fclose($myfile);
                            sleep(1);
                            $final_xml1 = null;
                            $final_xml = null;
                            //Mobile XML Code starts here//
                            $final_xml_mb1=<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">\n$final_xml_mb</urlset>
EOT;
                            $file_name_mb="$filePath/$file_num.xml";
                            $no_of_files_mb .= <<<EOT
https://somepath-$file_num.xml (Have Complete 20000 Url's)\n
EOT;
                            $myfile1 = fopen($file_name_mb, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$file_name_mb \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
                            fwrite($myfile1,$final_xml_mb1);
                            fclose($myfile1);
                            sleep(1);
                            $final_xml_mb = null;
                            $final_xml_mb1 = null;
                            $xml = null;
                            //Mobile XML code ends here//
                            echo "not real: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024)." MiB\n";
//                             ob_flush();
//                             echo "not real: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024)." MiB\n";
                    }
            }
            if($counter>0 && $counter<20000)
            {
                    $file_num++;
                    $final_xml=<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">\n$final_xml</urlset>
EOT;
                    $file_name=<<<EOT
$filePath/$file_num.xml
EOT;
                    $no_of_files .=<<<EOT
https://www.somefilepath$file_num.xml (Have Complete $counter Url's)\n
EOT;
                    $myfile = fopen($file_name, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$file_name \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
                    fwrite($myfile,$final_xml);
                    fclose($myfile);
                    sleep(1);
                    $final_xml = '';

                    //Mobile XML Code starts here//
                    $final_xml_mb=<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">\n$final_xml_mb</urlset>
EOT;
                    $file_name_mb="$filePath/$file_num.xml";
                    $no_of_files_mb .= <<<EOT
https://somefilepath-$file_num.xml (Have Complete $counter Url's)\n
EOT;
                    $myfile1 = fopen($file_name_mb, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$file_name_mb \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
                    fwrite($myfile1,$final_xml_mb);
                    fclose($myfile1);
                    sleep(1);
                    $final_xml_mb = '';
                    $xml = null;
                    //Mobile XML code ends here//
//                     ob_flush();

            }

            $msg='';
            $this->write_index_xml($file_num);
            $this->write_mb_index_xml($file_num);
            if($records==20000 && $global_record < $total_count)
            {
                $start= $global_record+1;
                if(($total_count-$global_record)> 20000)
                    $end = $global_record+20000;
                else
                    $end = $global_record+($total_count-$global_record);

                oci_free_statement($sthsplit);
                $this->fetch_data($start,$end,$total_count,$dbh);
            }

    }

    public function write_index_xml($count)
    {
            global $filePath;
            $s=0;
            $newmasterfile = $sitemap_index_final = $sitemap_index_file_name = '';
            $mtime = date("Y-m-d").'T'.date("G:i:s");

            $sitemap_index_final=<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
EOT;
            for($s=1;$s<=$count;$s++)
            {
                $sitemap_index_final .=<<<EOT
    <sitemap>
            <loc>https://www.somefilepath$s.xml</loc>
            <lastmod>$mtime+5:30</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
EOT;
            }

            $sitemap_index_final .='</sitemapindex>';
            $sitemap_index_file_name="$filePath/indexSSL.xml";

            if(file_exists($sitemap_index_file_name))
            {
                $newmasterfile = "$filePath/indexSSL.xml\n";
            }
            $myfile = fopen($sitemap_index_file_name, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$sitemap_index_file_name \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
            fwrite($myfile,$sitemap_index_final);
            fclose($myfile);
            $newmasterfile = $sitemap_index_final = $sitemap_index_file_name = null;
    }

    public function write_mb_index_xml($count)
    {
            global $filePath;
            $s=0;
            $newmasterfile = $sitemap_index_final = $sitemap_index_file_name = '';
            $mtime = date("Y-m-d").'T'.date("G:i:s");

            $sitemap_index_final=<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
EOT;
            for($s=1;$s<=$count;$s++)
            {
                $sitemap_index_final .=<<<EOT
    <sitemap>
            <loc>https://somefilepath-$s.xml</loc>
            <lastmod>$mtime+5:30</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
EOT;
            }

            $sitemap_index_final .='</sitemapindex>';
            $sitemap_index_file_name="$filePath/prod.xml";

            if(file_exists($sitemap_index_file_name))
            {
                $newmasterfile = "$filePath/prod.xml\n";
            }
            $myfile = fopen($sitemap_index_file_name, "w") or die("\nFailed To Open File \n$sitemap_index_file_name \nAt LINE: ".__LINE__ ."\nIn FILE:".__FILE__);
            fwrite($myfile,$sitemap_index_final);
            fclose($myfile);
            $newmasterfile = $sitemap_index_final = $sitemap_index_file_name = null;
    }

    public function connect($userid,$password,$dbName)
    {
            $dbh = oci_connect($userid,$password,$dbName);
            if ($dbh)
                return $dbh;
            else
            {
                $emsg    = oci_error();
                $msg.= "\n\n {$emsg['message']}\n\n";
                echo "\n\n not connected $msg \n\n";
                exit;
            }
    }
```

`

Comment: Not sure if this is better suited on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you tried actually using that `dbh` you're passing to `fetch_data` instead of ignoring it and opening a new connection every time?

Comment: @ChatterOne yes, that type change i have already tested.

Comment: i have made 2 different simple script, one for perl and another for php, and to  my surprise these scripts proves that perl takes almost one fourth time than PHP in command line scripting(cron jobs)

Comment: Conclusion: Perl is better than PHP. Use Perl.

Comment: Yes based on test, it proved that perl is better than PHP in scripting

Answer (score 0):

i have made 2 different simple script, one for perl and another for php, and to my surprise these scripts proves that perl takes almost one fourth time than PHP in command line scripting(cron jobs)

**Sample PHP Script:**

```
<?php

$start_time = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
for($i=1;$i<=20000000;$i++)
{
     echo 'hello world';
}
$time_end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
$cron_time = ($time_end - $start_time);
$cron_time = intval($cron_time);
echo "\ntime taken===".$cron_time;
?>
```

**PERL Script Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my $time_start = time();
for(my $i=1;$i<=20000000;$i++)
{
     print 'hello world';
}
my $time_end = time();
my $cron_time = $time_end - $time_start;
$cron_time = int($cron_time);
print "\ntime taken===".$cron_time;
```

Perl script is taking 17 Sec while php took 66 Sec.